# How to connect to SQL Server from visual studio Mac?

Tags: sql-server, macos, visual-studio

I tried to connect to a remote SQL Server using visual studio Mac using this

```
"Server=PcName;Database=DatabaseName;user=eg;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

but cannot connect this and this error appears from terminal in Mac:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

Is this way correct? If not which is the right way?

Comment: In theory it's correct. So you need to check the following (as the error message suggests) 1. The SQL Server on the remote machine is up and running. 2) Check the SQL Server is configured to accept remote connections. 3) check you can access the SQL Server from your Mac - e.g. can you try to make a telnet connection on port 1433, or ping the remote machine? That will tell you if any firewall or network path is blocking you. Maybe try using IP address instead of PC name, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Azure Data Studio, this is ssms for non windows machines.

Answer (score -1):

Your connection is correct,Try restarting your sql server and agent...